# How do I import a class with its updated state in React.js

Tags: class, import, export, state, reactjs

I have a class called Scanned.js which has an initial state of

```
export default class Scanned extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          name: "No Name Found",
          licensePlate: "No License Plate Found",
          registrationNumber: "No Number Found",
          referencePlate: "No Plate to Reference"
    };
```

this then gets updated within the render part of Scanned.js so that

```
this.state = {
      name: "No Name Found",
      licensePlate: "Jon",
      registrationNumber: "FJG-333",
      referencePlate: "FJG-333"
    };
```

I then go to another file and do

```
import Scanned from "./Scanned";

console.log(Scanned.state.name);
```

And I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong, and how do I import the class properly so that I get the updated values of that belong to the state and use the name value?

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: I get an error saying "unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export var props_scanned;
export default class Scanned extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          name: "No Name Found",
          licensePlate: "No License Plate Found",
          registrationNumber: "No Number Found",
          referencePlate: "No Plate to Reference"
    };
    props_scanned = this

}
```

Now in another file,

Make sure that your import path is correctly defined.

```
import {props_scanned} from './Scanned';

console.log(props_scanned.state.name);
```